# Возможно ли в Pug подставлять родительский селектор?

Tags: html, css, sass, pug

В Sass можно использовать символ & для обозначения родительского селектора, есть ли подобная функция в Pug?
Например

```
.my_class
    &_inner
        &_more
```

и чтоб на выходе получилось:

```
<div class="my_class">
    <div class="my_class_inner">
        <div class="my_class_inner_more"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подсказали в другом месте, может кому то пригодится
Есть специальный пакет для gulp - bemto.pug и он прекрасно работает по БЭМ методологии, подставляя родительские селекторы

Comment: Пернесите пожалуйста основное по ссылке прямо в тело ответа. Ссылки имеют свойство "протухать" и тогда ваш ответ уже никому не поможет и станет полносьтью бесполезным.